# Azure Function EventHubTrigger running multiple instances

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm having a problem running multiple instances of Azure functions that are supposed to be targeting same IoTHub endpoint (the default one) but different consumer group (required groups are created on the portal). Basically I want to process the same message twice but on different functions. So I have written two function projects with same setup (same storage, same endpoint and config) and only targeting different consumer group like in sample provided here [Event Hubs features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#consumer-groups)
If I run each project separately they both work just fine, the problem is if I run any of the projects first and then start the second one I get an error that that IServiceProvider is disposed. Error in output window:

Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.dll

Function implementation as simple as it gets:

```
    [FunctionName("MessageFunction")]
    public static async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("myActualEventHubName", Connection = "HubConnection", ConsumerGroup = "StoreMap")]OrderRecord message, ILogger log)
    {
        try
        {
            if (message != null)
            {
                log.LogInformation($"Got a valid message");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }

            log.LogInformation($"Event Hub trigger function processed a message: {message}");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.LogError("Error while processing.", e);
        }
    }
```

[image: Function error]

**Is this achievable or am I missing something or is this just a bug in some library? Any help appreciated.**

.Net Core 2.1

Tools:
VisualStudio 15.9.2

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools 15.10.2046.0

Installed Nugets:

Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.24

Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs 3.0.1

Comment: Seems like this might be due to running multiple functions from same machine, if I have one of the instances deployed on cloud and one running on my own machine then it all seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is caused by the occupied TCP port. When function host starts locally, it listens to port 7071 by default. We need to specify different ports to allow multiple instances running together.

Right click on your project> Properties> Debug, in Application arguments section add `host start -port 7072`.